# Functions is executed before the data is taken from state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have send some a number i.e 1, from another file using navigation. and  in this file i am fetching json data and want to compare if both json file having same number inside it. and i want that the product state is updated before calling the matchedProduct function. but it not works. please help me ..

```jsx
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
const location = useLocation();
const p_id = location.state.id;

async function fetchMatchedData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("./solo_product_details.json");
    //waits until the request completes...
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Success:", result);
    result.then((data) => setProduct(data));
    setProduct(result.data);
    setTimeout(() => {
      matchedProduct();
    }, 2000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMatchedData();
}, []);

const matchedProduct = () => {
  let pro_match = product.find((data) => data.id === p_id);
  if (pro_match) {
    alert("matched");
  } else {
    alert("not matched");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just refactor the code to pass the data to function or add a `useEffect` to execute every time when `product` changes.

```jsx
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
const location = useLocation();
const p_id = location.state.id;

async function fetchMatchedData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("./solo_product_details.json");
    //waits until the request completes...
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Success:", result);
    result.then((data) => setProduct(data));
    setProduct(result.data);
    matchedProduct(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMatchedData();
}, []);

const matchedProduct = (data) => {
  let pro_match = data.find((data) => data.id === p_id);
  if (pro_match) {
    alert("matched");
  } else {
    alert("not matched");
  }
};
```

or else,

```jsx
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
const location = useLocation();
const p_id = location.state.id;

async function fetchMatchedData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("./solo_product_details.json");
    //waits until the request completes...
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log("Success:", result);
    result.then((data) => setProduct(data));
    setProduct(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMatchedData();
}, []);

// Executes every time `product` changes
useEffect(() => {
  if(product.length > 0) {
    matchedProduct();
  }
}, [product]);

const matchedProduct = () => {
  let pro_match = product.find((data) => data.id === p_id);
  if (pro_match) {
    alert("matched");
  } else {
    alert("not matched");
  }
};
```